# Why nest js giving dependency injection error when i also imported modules in app module?

Tags: javascript, express, nestjs, backend, nest

this is my codes:

Auth Module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '365d',
      }
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Auth Controller:

```
@Controller("api")
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AuthService, private readonly jwtService:JwtService ) {}
}
```

Auth Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private userRepo:Repository<User>) {}
}
```

Auth Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private readonly jwtService:JwtService,private readonly userService:AuthService) {}
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    return ...
  }
}
```

App Module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'nestjs',
      entities: [User,Post],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Post]),
  ],
  controllers: [PostController],
  providers: [PostService],

})
export class AppModule{}
```

And i have this error:
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, AuthService). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [0] is available in the AppModule context
.

i defined jwt service in auth module and i imported auth module in app module, but the error says i should import jwt service in app module, why?

i also checked my imports in app module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that in the `AppModule`'s `PostController` you are using this `AuthGuard` class via `@UseGuards(AuthGuard)`. When you do this, Nest will try to create an instance of that guard in the context of the current controller's module (in this case `AppModule`). For that to happen, Nest will look at the parameters of the `AuthGuard` and pull them from the module's context, first by looking at immediate `providers`, then looking at the `exports` of the modules in the `imports` array. If those providers are not found, an error will be thrown.

In your case, in your `AuthModule` you should add `AuthService` and `JwtModule` to the `exports` array, to provide access to `AuthService` directly, and to provide access to `JwtService` via [Module Re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting). Your final `AuthModule` should look something like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '365d',
      }
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Now, in whatever controller class you need to use this `AuthGuard`, make sure to add `AuthModule` to the controller's module's imports, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help, problem is solved. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Alongwith authService you need to add JWTService to providers in auth.module. If you are using any additional service then add it too in auth.module providers.If your error still persists let me know in comments.

Comment: not resolved:

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '365d',
      }
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [JwtService,AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}